Assistance Needed with Left Joined Custom Report
Assistance Needed with Left Joined Custom Report
I have a custom report that combines two objects, Intakes (Leads) and Matters (Intakes converted to Matters), using a left join. I opted for a left join because I want all Intakes to be included, regardless of whether they have associated Matters. The primary object in this report is Intakes.
The goal of this report is to provide a summary for my manager’s dashboard, showing the number of Intakes/Leads that were referred out in a given month. An Intake can be referred out at the Intake Level by changing its status to “Referred Out” and its class to “Ref,” or it can be referred out after being converted to a Matter, in which case the status on the Intake changes to “Converted” and the class becomes “Ref.” In the case of Matters, the status is “Referred Out” and the class is “Ref.”
Both Intakes and Matters have a field called “Referred to,” which indicates the name of the referral partner to whom the case was referred. When an Intake is referred out at the Intake Level, this field is filled in the Intake object. When it is referred out at the Matter Level, the field is filled in the Matter object.
I am trying to create a report that shows the total number of cases referred out in a month and to which referral partner, either at the Intake Level or the Matter Level.
In Excel, I could easily create another column and use a formula like an IF statement to determine the “Referred to” value based on whether it is filled in the Intake or Matter. However, this is not an option for this report, as it needs to be displayed on my manager’s dashboard.
In Salesforce reports, I am unable to add a row-level formula to this report because it is based on a left join, and I cannot use the OR filter logic. Attempting to do so results in an error stating that the OR statement cannot be used in left join reports.
My current option seems to be creating two separate reports, one for Intakes and one for Matters, but this is not ideal as it requires my manager to manually calculate the totals for each referral partner. I am seeking a solution to create one combined report.
Any assistance or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.


You solve these types of problems at the data model level rather than the report level. 2. Do you understand the problem you're trying to solve? the goal of this report is show the number of Intakes/Leads that were referred out in a given month This is like leads converted to opportunities but in the Legal universe. The rest of your question contradicts your stated goal.


So what are u suggesting? My goal is total referral in a give month. Be it at the intake level or at the matter level after an intake is converted.

Count the referred intakes, including converted intakes.
